# image from androidphone via insecure adb to ubuntu pc fails via netcat (permission issue + broken pipe) - what is the reason?

Tags: ubuntu, android, dd, netcat, adb

I am using following tutorial to get an backup-image from my android phone (to recover lost pictures via photorec on ubuntu):
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/extracting-data-physically-dd

I am lost at the following operation:

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p19 bs=512 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync | /dev/Examiner_Folder/nc –l –p 9999
```

which results in

```
root@kodiak:/ # dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p19 bs=512 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync |> /system/bin/sh: /dev/Examiner_Folder/nc: can't execute: Permission denied [1] + Stopped (signal)     dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p19 bs=512 conv=not|
  Done (126)           /dev/Examiner_Folder/nc –l –p 9999
```

`stdout: write error: Broken pipe`
`1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.137 secs (0 bytes/sec)`

I am using adbd-Insecure-v2.00
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590

mobile: Amazon Fire (Fire OS 4.6.6.1)
PC: UBUNTU 15.10

Edit: since

```
chmod +x /dev/Examiner_Folder/nc
```

didn't work, I used

```
chmod 666 /dev/Examiner_Folder/nc
```

maybe the problem is connected to that issue?

Comment: Debugging 101: If a complicated command fails, break it down into pieces and see which one(s) work and which one(s) fail.  In particular, if you’re getting a `/dev/Examiner_Folder/nc: can't execute: Permission denied` error message, try running just `/dev/Examiner_Folder/nc` by itself.  And, yes, if you chmod’ed your executable to 666, that is a problem. P.S. Do you have thing(s) running in the background when you do this?